# DataMatrix convolutional codes

Tags: coding-theory

I'm trying to decode datamatrix code ECC 000-050 it uses convolutional codes for error correction.

Could someone explain me how to decode the stream (e.g. few first bytes of the stream) or give some pseudocode... ?

For example I have protected bit stream:

```
0000 1010 1011 1111 1010 1010 1010 0000 0100 0011 0110 1000 0101 0001 1000 0000 1110 1010 1001 1010 1001 1000 0100 1010
```

How can I receive the original unprotected bit stream from it?

```
000 101 001 101 010 101 110 011 000 000 001 001 011 110 110 011 111 011 111 111 110 000 000 000
```

I read than I can use Fano algorithm (But I can't find any detailed description of it).
For this code *Single bit penalty* = 31 and *delta* = 20

Could you explain me how to decode it (or any shorter example) with Fano algorithm (or any other easier to understand) ?

Comment: You need to know what the _encoder_ looks like to make a start at a decoding algorithm.  Perhaps the encoder is specified in the documentation of the "datamatrix code ECC 000-050"

Comment: The encoder is 4-3-3 (4 outputs, 3 inputs and 3 registers)

Comment: Good. Now, what are the _lengths_ of the registers, and where are the _taps_? The taps might be specified as a bunch of _polynomials_ of small degree (perhaps less than $6$ or $7$).

Comment: I found a very good document for beginners (like me) where step by step on the simple example the decoding is shown: http://complextoreal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/convo.pdf
I don't understand one think - how to compute the current threshold value ?